# Resistor ladder with digital (interrupt) and analog (analogRead) output

Tags: circuit-design

I want to create a resistor ladder with 3 switches with the following properties:

- if no switch is pressed, no current must be flowing
- when any of the switches is pressed, a line is set "high" to the input voltage (3.3v)
- when switch 1 is pressed, I want voltage a, switch 2 = voltage b, switch 3 = voltage c, while the exact voltages are not important as long as they are at least 0.1v apart from eachother

I am an electronics noob and read myself into it, and created the following drawing. I think it's not correct, and any hints on how to achieve the above would be awesome.

Thanks
Raphi[image]

Comment: What if two switches are pressed? The combined voltage produced may deliver the same voltage as the other switch being pressed on its own. Have you considered that? Have you also considered that if there is any voltage present you can detect that and use that is an indicator that a button is pressed thus getting rid of the need for a digital input line? Then if you use that freed-up line and another digital input line (not an analogue line) you could detect all three buttons being pressed using diodes.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks! Multipress is not a problem in that special case. And since this circuit will be read by an Arduino, which I want to put to sleep, I need to be able to read that "digital reading" pin digital, so either it's 3.3v or 0v.

Comment: Assuming the negative terminal of the supply is Ground, the analog reading will always be 3.3 volts.  Why the Zener diodes?

Comment: @PeterBennett Zener: I thought because otherwise all switches are basically shorted and I need to avoid backwards current? You are right about the analog reading, how would I need to connect it? I see that it doesn't make sense but don't know what to change :-|

Comment: @jsotola I don't think so ;-) as said in the title, I want to use an interrupt (thus digital) to "wake" the CPU, otherwise it's sleeping. You can't use an analog pin for an interrupt

Comment: use a very low power microcontroller to handle the three buttons ... something that is able to wake up on any pin transition .... the microcontroller would send an interrupt to your main system ... the same data pin could he used to transmit the button data, maybe as pulse width